# Use Lagrange multipliers to find the maximum and the minimum of $f$?

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

> Use Lagrange multipliers to find the maximum and the minimum of f subject to the given constraint(s) $f(x,y)=xyz$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=3$.

So far we have 
$$\begin{align}
f(x,y)&=xyz\\
g(x,y)&=x^2+y^2+z^2-3\\
f_x&=yz\\
f_y&=xz\\
\lambda g_x&=2x\lambda\\
\lambda g_y&=2y\lambda\\
f(x,y)&=2x^2\lambda\\
f(x,y)&=2y^2\lambda,
\end{align}$$

so $x=y$.
So I figured $x$ has to equal $1$ or $-1$. So the max is $1$ and the min is $-1$, but is this the right way to go about the problem?

Comment: looks like you have set $z=\pm 1$ somewhere - are you sure the problem isn't 3-D with $f(x,y,z)=xyz$ ?

Comment: yes thats how it is written on the worksheet given